# Proguard build failed(Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, android-proguard

This question already have been asked many times, but I am not able to resolve it.   I am trying to export my app using eclipse for final release, but I am getting the below error.

I already added

```
-keep class com.afollestad.materialdialogs.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.afollestad.materialdialogs.**
-dontshrink
```

Error resolved, but after running my app crashed.
please help me

this is the error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: com.afollestad.materialdialogs.util.DialogUtils: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.ColorStateList getColorStateList(int)' in class android.content.Context
Warning: com.afollestad.materialdialogs.util.DialogUtils: can't find referenced method 'int getColor(int)' in class android.content.Context
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
You may need to recompile them and try again.
Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? "Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'. "

Comment: @Shmuel i try this but i get same error :-(